# paperclip process file contents before upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, upload, paperclip

I want to compute a hash before uploading a file so that no duplicates are stored on the server.

Using the paperclip gem, what's the best approach to do processing on a file before saving it or inserting data in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveModel has a callback `before_create` (among others) which would make an ideal place for you compute something before the record is created. For a full list of the callbacks available, see the [Ruby on Rails Guides: Active Record Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks).

```
class Asset
  has_attached_file :image
  before_create :do_something
  def do_something
  end
end
```